# Creat virtual sink in pulseaudio combining two sources in specific way

Tags: ubuntu, audio, pulseaudio, software-rec

Basically what I wanna do is create a virtual sink in pulseaudio that will have my microphone input on one channel and my output mixed down to mono on the other. Is this possible? I'm on Ubuntu 19.10 if that's relevent

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Use `module-null-sink` for the "virtual sink", `module-loopback` with channel map twice to connect the mic source to the one channel, and the `.monitor` source of your output sink to the other (enable remix for this one).

Details for parameters in the [Pulseaudio modules documentation](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/).

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm kinda an idiot and newish to linux.